# I have a nested while loop and the father while loop will keep looping rather than ending with break

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made a nested while code and option 1 is the only one that works. It will break both while loops while options 2 and 3 only break their loops? I've tried copy-pasting the code for option 1 for the other 2 but alas no change.

```
#Volunteering
while True:
    print( Fname, " ", Lname, ", would you like to be a volunteer? [Y] [N]")
    VOLUNTEERyn = input()
    if VOLUNTEERyn == "Y":
            while True:
                print("Where would you like to work?")
                print("[1] Peir entrance gate")
                print("[2] Gift Shop")
                print("[3] Painting and decorating the Peir")
                print("Choose [1] or [2] or [3]")
                VOLUNTEERLOCATION = input()
                if VOLUNTEERLOCATION == "1":
                                          print("You now volunteer at the Peir entrance")
                                          break
            break            
            if VOLUNTEERLOCATION == "2":
                                        print("You now volunteer at the Gift Shop")
                                        break
            break                        
            if VOLUNTEERLOCATION == "3":
                                        print("You now volunteer as a Painter and Decorater")
                                        break
            break
```

I tried changing the indents to fix the problem but to no avail

Comment: Try the methods here: [Breaking out of nested loops](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/5-ways-to-break-out-of-nested-loops-in-python-4c505d34ace7)

Comment: First, fix the indents.  That's a must, right now if 2-3 and the break before if 2 are on the outer while loop, and not the inner.

2nd, walk through it with paper.  Think about what each line is doing (go slow), and how it reacts to input.  Pay attention to indentation, and remeber that break IMMEDIATELY exits the loop, and does not run any more statements that are indented such that they're inside the loop that's being exited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure while the "would you like to be a volunteer" runs in a infinite loop, but this works :

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

Fname = "Herp"
Lname = "McDerp"

while True:
    print( Fname, " ", Lname, ", would you like to be a volunteer? [Y] [N]")
    VOLUNTEERyn = input()
    if VOLUNTEERyn == "Y":
        while True:
            print("Where would you like to work?")
            print("[1] Peir entrance gate")
            print("[2] Gift Shop")
            print("[3] Painting and decorating the Peir")
            print("Choose [1] or [2] or [3]")
            VOLUNTEERLOCATION = input()
            if VOLUNTEERLOCATION == "1":
                print("You now volunteer at the Peir entrance")
                break
            if VOLUNTEERLOCATION == "2":
                print("You now volunteer at the Gift Shop")
                break
            if VOLUNTEERLOCATION == "3":
                print("You now volunteer as a Painter and Decorater")
                break
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are troubles with indents and "break" operators.

The code below works nice:

```
#Volunteering
Fname = "John"
Lname = "Doe"
while True:
    print(Fname, " ", Lname, ", would you like to be a volunteer? [Y] [N]")
    VOLUNTEERyn = input()
    if VOLUNTEERyn == "Y":
        while True:
            print("Where would you like to work?")
            print("[1] Peir entrance gate")
            print("[2] Gift Shop")
            print("[3] Painting and decorating the Peir")
            print("Choose [1] or [2] or [3]")
            VOLUNTEERLOCATION = input()
            if VOLUNTEERLOCATION == "1":
                print("You now volunteer at the Peir entrance")
                break          
            if VOLUNTEERLOCATION == "2":
                print("You now volunteer at the Gift Shop")
                break                     
            if VOLUNTEERLOCATION == "3":
                print("You now volunteer as a Painter and Decorater")
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix indentation and use a boolean flag to break the first level loop.

```py
# Volunteering
Fname = "Peter"
Lname = "Rabbit"

stop = False
while not stop:
    print( Fname, " ", Lname, ", would you like to be a volunteer? [Y] [N]")
    VOLUNTEERyn = input()
    if VOLUNTEERyn == "Y":
        while True:
            print("Where would you like to work?")
            print("[1] Peir entrance gate")
            print("[2] Gift Shop")
            print("[3] Painting and decorating the Peir")
            print("Choose [1] or [2] or [3]")
            VOLUNTEERLOCATION = input()

            if VOLUNTEERLOCATION == "1":
                print("You now volunteer at the Peir entrance")
                stop = True
                break

            elif VOLUNTEERLOCATION == "2":
                print("You now volunteer at the Gift Shop")
                stop = True
                break

            elif VOLUNTEERLOCATION == "3":
                print("You now volunteer as a Painter and Decorater")
                stop = True
                break
```